# UNIX tool to dump a selection of HTML?

Tags: monitoring, scripting, grep, xml

I'm looking to monitor changes on websites and my current approach is being defeated by a rotating top banner. Is there a UNIX tool that takes a selection parameter (id attribute or XPath), reads HTML from stdin and prints to stdout the subtree based on the selection?

For example, given an html document I want to filter out everything but the subtree of the element with `id="content"`. Basically, I'm looking for the simplest HTML/XML equivalent to grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly not what you're looking for, but how about writing a quick script in Python, using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to process the HTML, and give you a sensibly structured object which you can access the content.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS
soup = BS(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read())
soup.findAll('a')[1]
#returns
<a onclick="gbar.qs(this)" href="http://video.google.co.uk/?hl=en&amp;tab=wv" class="gb1">Videos</a>
```

Comment: I was thinking about using Beautiful Soup but figured someone had recognized the problem and make a reusable component out of it already. Thanks for the example though.

Comment: I bet nobody has.  If you can be arsed to make it generic enough, i'd suggest you bung the project on googlecode or similar.

Comment: This is the strategy I went with. There's a lot of XML tools, but they don't cope with poorly written HTML. I've generalized the code a bit, but need to spend a bit more time UNIX styling it before publishing.

Comment: :) Cool.  Glad it was useful!

Answer (score 1):

write a Perl script with [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP.pm) and [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TreeBuilder-XPath/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder/XPath.pm) perhaps.

Comment: Effectively the same as my suggestion. I find BeautifulSoup to be somewhat more semantic than Perl's offering.  Depends what the OP prefers I guess!